# Execute commons-math Java class from a gradle task

Tags: java, gradle, plugins, build

I need to execute from a gradle task classes included on a jar file.

For instance I would like to create a gradle task able to execute the class FastMath(http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/download_math.cgi).

The current build.gradle script is the following:

```
apply plugin: 'java'


repositories {
   mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile files('/pathToJars/commons-math3-3.6.1.jar')
}

task t1 {
    doLast {
        println FastMath.abs(3)
    }
}
```

I get this error message:

> What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':t1'.
>   Could not get unknown property 'FastMath' for task ':t1' of type org.gradle.api.DefaultTask.

I understand I am missing the class import, for instance adding the following statement but I do not know how or where:

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.util.FastMath;
```

I am wondering what I am doing wrong or how the script has to be configured. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

EDIT 1: The code that actually works is the following:

```
apply plugin:'java'
import org.apache.commons.math3.util.FastMath;

buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

    dependencies {
      classpath 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'
    }
}

task t1 {
  doLast {
      println FastMath.abs(3)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you have multiple issues in your buildscript.

1. If you use `mavenCentral()` as repository, use the dependencies from there, you will gain transitive dependency resolution and automatic conflict resolution and you do not have to keep the libs in your VCS or wherever, so `compile files('/pathToJars/commons-math3-3.6.1.jar')` should actually be `compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'`.
2. As you correctly noted, you either have to use fully-qualified class names or imports, so either, replace `println FastMath.abs(3)` by `println org.apache.commons.math3.util.FastMath.abs(3)`, or add `import org.apache.commons.math3.util.FastMath` anywhere before. Typically this is done top-most in a file, just like for Java too.
3. Even if you would do both, it would not work, because you add the dependency to the compile classpath of your actual project. Instead you need it in the classpath of your buildscript, so you need to move the `dependencies` block inside a `buildscript` block and if you followed advice 1, then of course also the `repositories` block. You also need `classpath` instead of `compile` in the dependency declaration.